# How can you show how positions have changed after selection sort?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I coded a selection sort program and I was wondering if I wanted to add-on to it by showing how the positions of the values have changed, if it would be possible?

this is my selection sort code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SelectionSort {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // int[] arr = {5,4,3,2,1}; // This is my array
        int min = 0;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("No of elements : ");
        int noOfElements = sc.nextInt();
        int[] arr = new int[noOfElements];

        System.out.println("Give elements : ");
        for (int i = 0; i < noOfElements; i++) {
            arr[i] = sc.nextInt();

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            // Assume first element is min
            min = i;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
                if (arr[j] < arr[min]) {
                    min = j;
                }
            }
            int temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[min];
            arr[min] = temp;
            System.out.println("Sorted Elemenst : " + arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are your thoughts on how to proceed? What have you tried? [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Before you can tackle an implementation you have to decide what it would look like to "show how positions have changed".  What design have you come up with, not for the code or implementation, but just for the display?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get array after each iteration, then you should print at the end of each iteration using **[Arrays#toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(int[]))** to print complete array

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

      ...
      .....
        int temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[min];
        arr[min] = temp;
        System.out.println("Sorted Elements : " + Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if your 'task' is to write your own sort method, but if you are looking for sorting an array you should use this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] arr = {5,4,3,2,1};
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Never assume what a User might enter and therefore never assume that the first entry will be the minimum value.

This question has been showing up a lot in StackOverflow and therefore I can only **assume** this is homework. With this in mind I'm sure the assignment intent is to accept a specific number of random integer values from the User, place those values into a Integer Array, then sort that array in **ascending** order. While the sorting process is taking place show (display in console) what steps are taking place (which values are swapped within the array).

Here's a tip, research the **[Bubble Sort](https://www.javatpoint.com/bubble-sort-in-java)** and the little bit of code it takes to accomplish the sorting task of Integer numbers within a Integer Array. In general a Bubble Sort utilizes two **for** loops to carry out a sort. It is within the second **for** loop where you can detail the process (steps) taken to carry out the sort as towards which Array element values are swapped with other element values as the sort is carried out. It would be within the **if** statement code block which checks whether or not the previous Array element is greater than the current Array Element.

Good luck.